# Can you help me understand this EXIM Log?

Tags: linux, exim

I see this type of log commonly,

```
2021-06-25 08:00:06 1rpTwT-03DnAE-9G Sender identification U=redacted D=redacted.tld S=redacted@redacted.tld
```

I'm using resources such as https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html to better learn exim logs, the information is just quite dense to get through.

I suspect the above log is telling me the following SMTP error:

**smtp_syntax_error:** A log line is written for every SMTP syntax error encountered. An unrecognized command is treated as a syntax error. For an external connection, the host identity is given; for an internal connection using -bs the sender identification (normally the calling user) is given.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the log line in context. It's handling message 1rpTwT-03DnAE-9G. The lines before and after that including that message id will contain more information on what was happening. This is merely giving you information about the sender that was responsible for that message on the queue.